# How to serve lua pages/scripts the simple, pain-free way?

Tags: http, web-applications, lua, cgi

I make good use of Lua programming language for all sort of scripts from some time now, and I want to stay with it (it is my sixth language or something). But I can't find a solution to make very simple lua web applications, which is quite frustrating.

I've tried WSAPI, Orbit, mongrel2, and tir attempting to make a simple, straightforward system to serve some very simple lua CGI but I have failed, it ends up always in a system with tons of dependencies, not portable, and interspersed in a lot of files and dir and subdirs... I even tried to modify nanoki, same result. Sure I learned some things, but I am at the same point I was when I started. Lua seems to be not friendly in the web development field.

In Django or web2py, or php, I can make simple apps in three minutes. But I will bloat a simple script/functionality with tens of files. Or I have to use a language I hate moderately (php).

I need something that will stay out of my way, similar to web.py or cherrypy or pow for ruby, but in lua.

I compiled haserl, but I don't know how to use it as it lacks documentation (a common problem in lua world, sadly).
mod_lua/apache, may be good, but I haven't found a page on all internet with some sample usage. Same for mod_magnet in lighttpd, and nginx + lua.

I'm starting to feel frustrated. I don't need light speed servers on millions user website, I need to serve simple dynamic lua content over a lan. Which I don't think have to require a rocketscientist...

So, how would you proceed? There is somewhere a minimal, simple webserver supporting standard cgi in lua? Something that is plug and play and let you and me concentrate on what the script does, instead of how to make simple things absurdly complicated in evil ways?

PS: My environments is Linux.

Comment: Can you do php without Apache? I didn't think that was possible.

Answer (score 5):

Have you heard about **Luvit**? It is basically **NodeJS** in Lua

[Official Luvit Homepage](http://luvit.io/)

[Github Repo](https://github.com/luvit/luvit)

A simple script would look like this:

```
local HTTP = require("http")

HTTP.create_server("0.0.0.0", 8080, function (req, res)
  local body = "Hello world\n"
  res:write_head(200, {
    ["Content-Type"] = "text/plain",
    ["Content-Length"] = #body
  })
  res:finish(body)
end)

print("Server listening at http://localhost:8080/")
```

[Here](http://lua-list.2524044.n2.nabble.com/ANN-Luvit-Lua-UV-Jit-NodeJS-re-implemented-in-Lua-td7048032.html) is the original post from the creator.

Comment: This code has been changed with latest luvit. Please refer the latest example on https://luvit.io/

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point to a CGI Library I wrote for Lua that addresses the exact problems you named - dependencies.

LunarCGI is, at its core, only 3 files (only the Lunar*.lua files are required), supporting HTML Templates (and even simple fileuploading, although it doesn't support binary files [yet!]).

Give it a try: https://github.com/beelzebub/lunarcgi

Comment: hiobs, thanks, it is pure beauty. I have made a setup similar to what I wanted to accomplish in less than ten minutes with thttpd. Finally something to hack on to make this nasty little cgi. Have you suggestion about other http server? What do you use?

Comment: Personally I'm using apache, but LunarCGI is written to be server agnostic, so it should run fine on most setups

Comment: You made a really good work. My unique concern is it's speed, it seems a little slow () haven't done any benchmark yet, just my impression), but I think this an implicit limit of CGI interfaces... What do you think?

Comment: Depends; The template library part compiles the HTML templates into raw Lua code, which is then executed on the fly, so that should be arguably fast. The speed however also depends on your algorithms. I've found LunarCGI to be pretty fast, so maybe it might be just the Template part? In any way, you might want to register at github, then issue a bugreport at https://github.com/beelzebub/lunarcgi/issues

Comment: I know it is a bit old, but the project (LunarCGI) does not seem to exist anymore

Answer (score 1):

Try [Civetweb](https://github.com/civetweb/civetweb), it's a small, powerful and embeddable web server. It can serve lua pages and even has built-in sqlite support, so you can have a database for your web application. It also supports cgi, as you requested. Binaries for Windows are available on [Github](https://github.com/civetweb/civetweb/releases/latest).

Answer (score 0):

If writing the code is your main problem, Orbit also comes with [Lua Pages](http://keplerproject.github.com/orbit/pages.html) , which seems similar to php in usage (so you inline code in your html).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I tried Orbit and personally I don't like it very much, at least for the current project